# How to change the position of Polybar?

Tags: gentoo, i3

So I have Polybar configured in i3 (I am using Gentoo), and I want to change its position from top to left. I have checked its GitHub page and tried looking at other places too, but couldn't find a way. Is it even possible? If yes, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polybar apparently cannot be used as a vertical bar, see [Provision for vertical bars?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Polybar/comments/hwcxy2/) asked on Reddit in 23 July 2020.